# trying to store objects in an ArrayList as a reference

Tags: android

Here is my array

```
arrayLayout = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
```

I'm adding my linearLayouts in a loop using

```
arrayLayout.add(info);
```

And I'm trying to remove the layout using the following in a method

```
arrayLayout.get(gallery.getSelectedItemPosition()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But it doesnt do anything. I think it's because I'm not referencing the object properly.
Should I be referencing object using an Array instead of an ArrayList? If so, how do I do it?

Comment: what makes you think that your are getting the correct array index value from your gallery, have you verified?

Comment: i think you're right. gallery.getSelectedItemPosition() doesnt give a value when it supposed to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with you using an ArrayList. I believe your problem is that you are not getting the correct index. Can you please post more code? This will help us better assist you in a faster fashion.